# Unresolved reference to TSocket

Tags: python, intellij-idea, thrift

I am having a problem in making intellij idea find the TSocket, TTransport and Tserver.

[image]

I have thrift installed properly, and I was able to generate my `.thrift` file.
And here is the version of it:

[image]

I am adding the path in the server it self to the library:

```
sys.path.insert(0, glob.glob('../thrift-0.10.0/lib/py/build/lib.*')[0])
```

Inside this path there's:

[image]

Any idea how I can resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably because it is not recognizing the thrift module.

Look [here](http://thrift-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-example.html):

> ImportError: No module named Thrift

This can be easily fixed by going to the directory **lib/py** on the thrift installation directory and run the following command to install the thrift module to your python libraries:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```